# Finding unique users from linked values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, google-bigquery

I have values in my Table of this form.

```
id | val1  | val2 
--------------------
1  |   e1  |   m1
2  |   e1  |   m2
3  |   e2  |   m2
4  |   e3  |   m1
5  |   e4  |   m3
6  |   e5  |   m3
7  |   e5  |   m4
8  |   e4  |   m5
```

From this, I have to recover unique users like this and give them a unique id to identify.

User1 -> (val1 : e1, e2, e3 | val2: m1, m2)

e1 <-> m1, e1 <-> m2, m1 <-> e3, e2 <-> m2 ( <-> means linked).

e1 is connected to m1.

e1 is connected to m2.

m2 is connected to e2.

So e1,m1 are connected to e2.

Similarly, we find e1, e2, e3, m1, m2 all are linked. We need to identify these chains.

---

User2 -> (val1 : e4, e5 | val2: m3, m4, m5)

I have written two queries based on grouping my val1 and then by val2 separately and joining them in code (Java).

I want this to do this directly in MySQL/BigQuery query itself as we are building some reports on this.

Is this possible in a single query? Please help.

Thank you.

Update :

Desired output -

```
[
 { 
   id : user1,
   val1 : [e1, e2, e3],
   val2 : [m1, m2]
 },
 { 
   id : user2,
   val1 : [e4, e5],
   val2 : [m3, m4, m5]
 }
]
```

or

```
id | val1  | val2 | UUID
------------------------
1  |   e1  |   m1 | u1
2  |   e1  |   m2 | u1
3  |   e2  |   m2 | u1
4  |   e3  |   m1 | u1
5  |   e4  |   m3 | u2
6  |   e5  |   m3 | u2
7  |   e5  |   m4 | u2
8  |   e4  |   m5 | u2
```

To make it simple, assuming values of val1 and val2 are nodes and are connected if present in the same row.

The rows of the table form graphs (user1, user2) and we need to identify these graphs.

Comment: not clear  - what the logic of grouping  val1,2 into different users? show the query you mentioned you'done already - so it might help us understand the logic

Comment: Updated the question with explanation. My logic is semi code, semi query which groups them

Comment: got it - this makes sense now

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to Mikhail, but I'm still confused about the desired output here. Can you please show it in table form like you have for the input?

Comment: updated with even more info. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to jump-in with option of solving your task with pure BigQuery (Standard SQL)

**Pre-requisites / assumptions**:  source data is in `sandbox.temp.id1_id2_pairs`
You should replace this with your own or if you want to test with dummy data from your question  - you can create this table as below (of course replace `sandbox.temp` with your own `project.dataset`)

[image]
Make sure you set respective destination table

**Note**: you can find all respective Queries (as text) at the bottom of this answer, but for now I am illustrating my answer with screenshots - so all is presented - query, result and used options

So, there will be three steps:

Step 1 - **Initialization**

Here, we just do initial grouping of id1 based on connections with id2:
[image]

As you can see here - we created list of all id1 values with respective connections based on simple one-level connection through id2

Output table is `sandbox.temp.groups`

Step 2 - **Grouping Iterations**

In each iteration we will enrich grouping based on already established groups.
Source of Query is output table of previous Step (`sandbox.temp.groups`) and Destination is the same table (`sandbox.temp.groups`) with Overwrite

[image]

We will continue iterations till when count of found groups will be the same as in previous iteration

[image]

**Note**: you can just have two BigQuery Web UI Tabs opened (as it is shown above) and without changing any code just run Grouping  and then Check again and again till iteration converge

(for specific data that I used in pre-requisites section  - I had three iterations - first iteration produced 5 users, second iteration produced 3 users and third iteration produced again 3 users  - which indicated that we done with iterations.

Of course, in real life case - number of iterations could be more than just three - so we need some sort of automation (see respective section at the bottom of answer).

Step 3 – **Final Grouping**
When id1 grouping is completed - we can add final grouping for id2

[image]

Final result now is in `sandbox.temp.users` table

**Used Queries** (do not forget to set respective destination tables and overwrites when needed as per above described logic and screenshots):

Pre-requisites:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 1 id, 'e1' id1, 'm1' id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    'e1',     'm2' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    'e2',     'm2' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,    'e3',     'm1' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,    'e4',     'm3' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,    'e5',     'm3' UNION ALL
SELECT 7,    'e5',     'm4' UNION ALL
SELECT 8,    'e4',     'm5' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,    'e6',     'm6' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,    'e7',     'm7' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,    'e2',     'm6' UNION ALL
SELECT 888,  'e4',     'm55'
```

Step 1

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS (select * from `sandbox.temp.id1_id2_pairs`
), x1 AS (SELECT id1, STRING_AGG(id2) id2s FROM `yourTable` GROUP BY id1
), x2 AS (SELECT id2, STRING_AGG(id1) id1s FROM `yourTable` GROUP BY id2 
), x3 AS (
  SELECT id, (SELECT STRING_AGG(i ORDER BY i) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT i FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(id1s)) i)) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT x1.id1 id, STRING_AGG((id1s)) id1s FROM x1 CROSS JOIN x2
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT y FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(id1s)) y WHERE x1.id1 = y)
    GROUP BY id1) 
)
SELECT * FROM x3
```

Step 2 - Grouping

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH x3 AS (select * from `sandbox.temp.groups`)
SELECT id, (SELECT STRING_AGG(i ORDER BY i) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT i FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(grp)) i)) grp
FROM (
  SELECT a.id, STRING_AGG(b.grp) grp FROM x3 a CROSS JOIN x3 b 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT y FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(b.grp)) y WHERE a.id = y)
  GROUP BY a.id )
```

Step 2 - Check

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT grp) users FROM `sandbox.temp.groups`
```

Step 3

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS (select * from `sandbox.temp.id1_id2_pairs`
), x1 AS (SELECT id1, STRING_AGG(id2) id2s FROM `yourTable` GROUP BY id1 
), x3 as (select * from `sandbox.temp.groups`
), f  AS (SELECT DISTINCT grp FROM x3 ORDER BY grp
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() id, grp id1, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(i ORDER BY i) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT i FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(id2)) i)) id2
FROM (
  SELECT grp, STRING_AGG(id2s) id2 FROM f 
  CROSS JOIN x1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT y FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(f.grp)) y WHERE id1 = y)
  GROUP BY grp)
```

**Automation**:
Of course, above "process" can be executed manually in case if iterations converge fast - so you will end up with 10-20 runs. But in more real-life cases you can easily automate this with any [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) of your choice

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now trying to extend this problem to more types of values (id1, id2  to id1, id2,id3, id4,id5 ...)  I would be running this on 6 million rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to use/implement above approach on your real data? Like using just two columns of your data with 6 million rows. Share your result  before we can go further

Comment: I was able to apply this to around 1500 rows using two columns. Will update   once I have completed for full data set

Comment: Update: Ran this query on 10,000 rows.  It took 3 iterations and it resolved to 295 unique users.  On inspecting manually, it worked fine except, there is a serious problem with null values. It merges two different users if any one of the values (id1 or id2) is null on any row. Basically, it merges based on null values also. Can we prevent this?

Comment: in Step 1 replace `WITH \`yourTable\` AS (select * from \`sandbox.temp.id1_id2_pairs\`)`  with `WITH \`yourTable\` AS (select * from \`sandbox.temp.id1_id2_pairs\` WHERE NOT(id1 IS NULL OR id2 IS NULL)` and most likely same for Step 3

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant : Want to do something very similar I tried your solution with 1 million rows input, but I suppose because of the CROSS JOIN it quickly hit my CPU seconds limit (in step 1).