# How to generate connected components given a large graph in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to generate the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of a graph using BigQuery.

Given, the following graph (represented by pairs of nodes that are connected):

```
(E1, E2)
(E2, E3)
(E3, E4)
(E4, E5)
```

We can conclude that all of these components are connected and therefore represent one connected component:

```
(E1, E2, E3, E4, E5)
```

Here are traditional algorithms used to generate the connected components of a graph:  [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

My initial thought was to recreate the pairs of nodes that match so that all entities eventually end up pointing to one common node (by making child nodes point to their ancestor nodes). So if (E1, E2) is a pair and (E2, E3) is a pair. I can write SQL logic to create a new pair (E1, E3) and then I can discard (E2, E3).

**Here is a more in-depth example:**

Input:

```
(E1, E2)
(E2, E3)
(E3, E4)
(E4, E5)
```

Iteration 1:

```
(E1, E2)
(E1, E3) which replaces (E2, E3)
(E2, E4) which replaces (E3, E4)
(E3, E5) which replaces (E4, E5)
```

Iteration 2:

```
(E1, E2)
(E1, E3)
(E1, E4) which replaces (E2, E4)
(E1, E5) which replaces (E3, E5)
```

I soon realized that this process takes a long time when the graph is large since we're performing only one hop at a time.

Is it possible to generate connected components faster given pairs of matches in a BigQuery table?

Input:

```
|--------------------|------------------|
|      Entity 1      |      Entity 2    |
|--------------------|------------------|
|         E1         |         E2       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|         E2         |         E3       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|         E3         |         E4       |
|--------------------|------------------|
|         E4         |         E5       |
|--------------------|------------------|
```

Desired Output:

I would like to write a query that reads in the input table above and outputs the following:

```
|--------------------|------------------|
|       Entity       |       Group      |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          E1        |         1        |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          E2        |         1        |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          E3        |         1        |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          E4        |         1        |
|--------------------|------------------|
|          E5        |         1        |
|--------------------|------------------|
```

Is this possible in BigQuery?

Comment: What's the logic in your query?

Comment: You should present logic you are looking for!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. What do you mean by logic?

Comment: explain how you would 'Generate Connected Components' by yourself based on example in your question  - so we understand what you want
'

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a single query, because BigQuery does not support recursive CTEs or other functionality to support graph walking.

Comment: @BrandonStanley - you don't expect us to just hardcode the output which we can easily do for you- right? so please take a time and spell out how you would get that result from that input data  - forget about sql - just how you would do this "manually". Btw, if it is graph related - I don't think your expected output is correct  - but I can be wrong obviously

Comment: ok. at least your recent update in input data makes expected output more reasonable :o) - so less confusion about logic - which still would be great to have one from  you

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47381317/5221944 - you might get some ideas from there

Answer (score 1):

What you need is recursive join:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_join

But since BigQuery does not directly support this,
what you can do is repeatedly join table with itself,
create a new table of connected components and do this
until the number of components does not change anymore.

Something like:

```
select a, min(if(c > a, a, c)) c 
from (select x.a, y.c from data x join data y on x.c = y.a)
group by a;
```

This assign component id `c` to each value based on minimum of its own value and id of connected value.

After each run, check

```
select count(distinct c) from data;
```

Once it stopped changing - you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` with window function to make it.

What's window function.

```
OVER (   
       [ <PARTITION BY clause> ]  
       [ <ORDER BY clause> ]   
       [ <ROW or RANGE clause> ]  
      )
```

> Determines the partitioning and ordering of a rowset before the associated window function is applied. That is, the OVER clause defines a window or user-specified set of rows within a query result set. A window function then computes a value for each row in the window.

so you can make row number by `Entity1`

```
SELECT  Entity1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Entity1) Group      
FROM T
```

[Row_number](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#row-number)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What would the purpose of the window function be?

Comment: @BrandonStanley I add more detail about window function